# Need help with algorithm to resolve index through jagged array

Tags: c#, algorithm

Argh!  I know I will get this eventually but at this point I'm almost 2 hours into it and still stuck.

I need to resolve the individual indexes for each "level" of a jagged array for a specific location.  It's hard to explain, but if you imagine a 3 level jagged array with [2,3,4] lengths.  If you then were to flatten that out into a single array it would have a size of 24.  Now, let's say you needed to find the the indexes (one for each level of the jagged array) that would be equal to the single array index 22.  It would be 1,2,1. It's not hard to figure out a single scenario, but I'm trying to figure out what the algorithm is to resolve these values for a variable depth jagged array.

Here is a simple code sample of my current attempt:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //  Build up the data and info about level depth
        int[] levelDepth = new[] { 2, 3, 4 };
        int[][][] data = new int[][][]
        {
            new int[][] { new int[4], new int[4], new int[4] },
            new int[][] { new int[4], new int[4], new int[4] }
        };

        int requestedValue = 22;
        float temp = requestedValue;

        //  Store the index of each level array to get to the index 
        //  for the requested value
        int[] levelIndexes = new int[3] { 0, 0, 0 };

        //  The following does not work!
        int i = levelDepth.Length;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            temp = temp / levelDepth[i - 1];
            levelIndexes[i - 1] = (int)Math.Round(temp);

            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work correctly, although it ALMOST gets me what I need but I think that just may be luck.  I suspect this is a common problem that has been solved before, I just don't have the experience to figure it out.  :(

Also, before anyone tells me that using arrays like this is terrible or "why don't you store your data like this" - The above description and code is simulating the layout of some decoder chips on our hardware and I need to work out a way to resolve a path to a specific graph of cascading chips;  the above example exactly matches the layout of the chips.  I'm stuck with it.

Comment: Do you need the actual indices, or just the actual element's value at that point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `float`s here.

```
int[] levelDepth = new[] { 2, 3, 4 };
int requestedValue = 22;
int[] levelIndexes = new int[levelDepth.Length];


for (int i = 0; i < levelDepth.Length; i++)
{
  // need to go from { 2, 3, 4 } -> { 3*4, 4, 1 }
  int f = 1;
  for (int j = i+1; j < levelDepth.Length; j++)      
     f *= levelDepth[j];

  levelIndexes[i] = requestedValue / f;  // integer divide
  requestedValue = requestedValue % f;
}
```

Comment: Modulo! - that's what I was missing (ok, maybe a few more pieces too) Your solution works well and will dynamically handle varying depth graphs which is important.  I also like that we ditch the float use, that was bugging me too.

Comment: Just a note, you don't seem to need jagged (array of array). `int[,,] data = new int[2,3,4];` would do and then `GetLength(level)` can replace `levelDepth[]`.

Comment: Is this algorithm in a textbook? It solved my problem but I've struggled to find a reference (other than permalinking to this answer).

Comment: @Jon - I don't think it's in any textbook, I improvised. And it's not really a textbook problem, although some smaller parts are.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need the element's value at that point (and not the specific indices), you can simply perform a ruby-like [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197081/291999), and then access the index directly.

Edit: Sorry for the misunderstanding, maybe this will help. From Microsoft Visual C#.NET 2003 Developers Cookbook (Mark Schmidt):

```
static int[] GetDimensionIndices(int flatIndex, Array array)
{
    int[] indices = new int[array.Rank];
    int p = 1;
    for(int i = array.Rank - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        indices[i] = (((flatIndex/p)) % (array.GetUpperBound(i)+1));

        if(i > 0)
            p *= array.GetUpperBound(i) + 1;
    }
    return indices;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with a potential solution I found in a book.

Comment: This is an interesting solution as well, if I could select two answers I would.  Thanks for posting the sample!

Answer (score 1):

Array of length 2 holds array of length 3, which holds array of length 4.

Thus, the index on the first array will increment your total index by 3*4=12.

Index on second array will increment your total by 4.

Index on third array will increment your total by 1.

So, 22 = 12*1 + 4*2 + 1*1.

After figuring out these numbers (multiply values in `levelDepth` together), you can simply use a greedy algorithm starting with the outermost array.

```
int temp = requestedValue;
int levelWeight[] = {levelDepth[2]*levelDepth[1], levelDepth[2], 1};
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    while(requestedValue >= levelWeight[i]){
        levelIndexes[i]++;
        requestedValue-=levelWeight[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the sample.  I think you are missing a decrement to temp (e.g. temp -= levelWeight[i]).  Also the last index is incorrectly resolved to 2 rather than 1

Comment: Actually, I'm incorrect on the final index comment; 2 is the correct value